# How do you restore app from trash?

Tags: applications

Accidently dragged an app into the "trash". How do I restore it to home screen? Do not know how to retrieve the app from trash.

Answer (score 2):

Dragging an app shortcut from the home screen into the little bin simply deletes the shortcut, not the app. You can recreate the shortcut this way:

- Find the app in the *app drawer* (that is, the list of all apps)
- Hold your finger on the app to pick it up
- The screen will change to the home screen
- Drop the app where you want on the home screen. You can move to the next screen by dragging to the edge of the screen.

On the other hand, if you drag the app icon from the app drawer to the bin, it will completely uninstall the app. It checks first, with the dialog, "Do you want to uninstall this app?" If you answer OK to that dialog, then the app is completely removed, and you can only get it back by installing it again in the usual way.